# Git merge master into orphan without commit history

Tags: git

Given an `orphan` branch without history, how would I incorporate changes done on `master` branch, since the moment of creation of the orphan, without copying all commits history when pushing the orphan remotely.

```
A <- B <- C <- D  

        orphan(created from state B) <-X <- Y
```

I would like to bring `c` and `d` to the orphan branch and then `x` and `y` to master.

If I do `checkout orphan, merge master` or `rebase master` orphan gets the commits, but also all history tree. such as when I push orphan to a remote server, everybody will be able to see all `master's` history as well.

Also later I would like to merge `orphan` back into master, bringing commits `x` and `y` there.

### Edit:

Now merging orphan into master works ok with `git merge`

```
A <- B <- C <- D <------X <- Y
                       /  
        orphan <-X <- Y
```

**But,** merging `master` back into `orphan` either puts the entire master history into orphan (such as becomes `X` preceded by `B`) or with cherry picking, but than I need to skip the merge-commits and also get a lot more conflicts

Comment: There's no such thing as a "branch without history": in Git, commits *are* history, and to have a branch name, you must have a commit: the branch name points to that commit (and its history is based on that commit's parent, the parent's parent, and so on). Your diagram doesn't draw the kind of branch created by `git checkout --orphan` either. Hence I cannot make any sense from your question.

Comment: There is some miscommunication somewhere in your question, because it is not possible to have a true "orphan" branch, i.e. a branch that does not share a common ancestor with other branches. They all must go all the way back to the initial commit.

Comment: If you meant that you wished to bring a commit from a repo to another unrelated repo, you  can use `git format-patch` to generate a patch file, and `git am` it in the target repo.

Comment: When I do 'git log' on an orphan branch only it doesnt show the history of anything else. The entire idea of orphan is 'no ancestor'. Or isn't it ?

Comment: Well I guess you are gonna have to show a series of actual commands that produce this "orphan branch", for us to better understand you.

Comment: `git checkout --orphan another`

Comment: @jingx: Using `git checkout --orphan` followed by `git commit`, you can create a branch whose history is unrelated to that of the existing branches. Or, to put this in more graph-theoretic terms, you can create a separate subgraph within the commit graph, starting from a new root commit. But that's not what Alex drew.

Comment: @torek, wow, didn't know about `--orphan`.  @Alex I suppose you could still cherry-pick C and D, then?

Comment: @jingx After cherry-picking all files modified files appear conflicted. I guess I would need a cherry pick with some merge strategy in place

Comment: Also if I just cherry pick the commits, I have to avoid the merge commits (after merging the orphan changes into master), resulting in later merges even more complicated

Comment: You're trying to merge 2 totally unrelated branch histories.. Of course you'll have to deal with the merge conflicts.. That's how git work

Comment: Or rebase orphan branch onto master branch and do interactive rebase and delete all the unwanted commits from orphan branch then push it to upstream

Comment: I want to rebase master's new commits on top of orphan, but avoid the orphan having all master's history after that.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea Git wasn't designed for. Nobody has asked "why would you want to do this"? Do you want to save data to transmit or on the server? Do you want to hide your commit history?

Comment: What is the purpose of working in git this way?  Why are you creating orphan branches in the first place?  I think the reason a solution is not obvious is because whatever your use case is can be solved more simply through other methods.  Why do you not want to push all of `master` history to the remote? i.e. It appears that `master` is really your local master, not the remote `master` and a simple correct branching strategy will remove the need to do anything crazy with an orphan branch...

Comment: @LightCC I'm trying to share a code with modified config with somebody else on a different remote git server, but I don't want them to have the history, so they cannot read the original config passwords

Comment: @Alex Added my answer based on that.  If this misses the mark, please help me understand how - happy to refine or suggest a different path.

Answer (score 2):

Grafts are built for exactly this.

```
root=$(git rev-list my-orphan-branch --max-parents=0)  # get the orphaned-branch root
echo $(git rev-parse $root B) >.git/info/grafts        # locally remember its real parent
```

and now all the local commands will know about the ancestry but it will remain repo-local, push and fetch won't export it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and what you are intending, I'm going to suggest an alternate workflow/design to avoid the need to do super-ordinary Git things.

It sounds like there are some special config files or settings with passwords or similar sensitive information that you don't want to pass back to the remote, that are baked into your compiled files in the repo.  Why not separate those out from the baked in code?  If these files are already separate, then you can just `.gitignore` them.  Regardless, it's better to have both a standard default that is compiled in or a default config file that gets distributed with the repo (and/or the application itself), and then have the code check for the presence of a custom config file, which is saved outside the repo or ignored with `.gitignore`.

Without knowing more about your setup (linux/PC/Mac, programming language, frameworks, etc.) it's difficult to give further guidance - for example, with Visual Studio development for C#, there is a `Properties.Settings` file that can be setup.  The defaults become a part of the compiled code, but a class gets auto-generated that will save out any changes to a user-specific file and reload it when the application launches, but this is in the user home directory, and not in the development folders.  Another method would be having the file locally, and using `.gitignore` to have Git not transfer it between repos.

I think this method will be better for you long-term, though might incur a short-term cost to update your design for better config management.  My concern is that if you need some non-standard Git wizardry every time you need to push changes will cause times where someone forgets to take the extra steps and pushes the sensitive info up to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git checkout orphan
git merge --no-commit --squash master
git commit
```